# Problemas com consumo Rest Java swing?

Tags: java, web-service, swing, rest

Tenho uma aplicação java swing onde eu pego uma lista de dados de um webservice. 
 Quando eu executo isso pelo netbeans ele faz certinho, agora quando eu gero o jar para enviar pro cliente, a aplicação simplesmente nao faz a requisição, ela trava. Segue a classe:

```
public class Rest {

    public void get() {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client
                .resource("...");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                .get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus()
                != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatus());
        }

        String[] result = new String[2];

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        result[0] = String.valueOf(response.getStatus());

        System.err.println(result[1]);

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JsonObject obj = parser.parse(output).getAsJsonObject();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Arquivo arquivo = gson.fromJson(obj, Arquivo.class);
    }

}
```

e aqui e onde meu botao chama

```
private void bt_listaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        new Rest().get();

    }
```

Comment: Não da erro? Já tentou rodar o jar por um terminal de comando do windows?

Comment: bem isso !!! , acabei de executar ! ele nao ta trazendo a dependencia !